# Editing files after a HiJackThis scan

Tags: windows-7

After a scan with HiJackThis I came across these sections:

> O15 - Trusted Zone: *.clonewarsadventures.com
>
> O15 - Trusted Zone: *.freerealms.com
>
> O15 - Trusted Zone: *.soe.com
>
> O15 - Trusted Zone: *.sony.com

Where are those entries written? I don't want them to be trusted at all. There's no indication in the HiJackThis logfile where those entries are written, just that they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find these settings in your internetsettings -> security -> trusted zone -> sites.
I hope I translated the options correct from german to english, so may some names are different.